# How to set the object name on json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm returning JSON from ASP.NET Web API. the Json  does return without a problem but at the beginning of the Json  array there is no object name for me to use in an android application.

is there anyway to set it?

here is the Json  that is being returned

THE OBJECT NAME SHOULD BE AT THE BEGINNING. NOT JUST STARTING WITH ID

```
[{"ID":1197,"CustomerGuid":"ea0af124-ab88-45d8-88f7-3f122ef53c04","UserTrackingID":"2624","EmailAddress":"m.mashoodtariq@gmail.com","Password":"Pakistan99","IsBusiness":null,"FullName":"Mashood","DateRegistered":"2014-11-26T18:51:47.977","PostCode":"44000","BusinessName":null,"FactualID":null,"FacebookToken":null,"Country":null},{"ID":1202,"CustomerGuid":"30c3781e-506c-490a-a27d-03a29696bdcd","UserTrackingID":"2643","EmailAddress":"customer@hotmail.com","Password":"george69","IsBusiness":null,"FullName":"Pending Customer","DateRegistered":"2014-11-27T08:08:04.29","PostCode":"4220","BusinessName":null,"FactualID":null,"FacebookToken":null,"Country":null},{"ID":1203,"CustomerGuid":"cf7d09e4-2e84-4b16-b38c-d32579d1c6c4","UserTrackingID":"2646","EmailAddress":"tesr@hotmail.com","Password":"george69","IsBusiness":true,"FullName":"tester","DateRegistered":"2014-11-28T00:12:40.523","PostCode":"4102","BusinessName":"tester","FactualID":null,"FacebookToken":null,"Country":null}]


Public Class UsersController
    Inherits System.Web.Http.ApiController

    Private db As New PushStateNovember7Entities
    ' GET: api/Users
    Function GetUsers() As IQueryable(Of User)
        Return db.Users
    End Function

End Class
```

you can also view the project live at and access the helppage @

- http://clzbyapi.azurewebsites.net/api/users
- http://clzbyapi.azurewebsites.net/help

Comment: Please show the class that you are serializing. Also, are you sing ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API? (Controller or ApiController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why would u need a name at the beginning. If all u need is to parse the Json array in Android, you could do something like this:

Say you have the following User class:

```
public class User {
    private string _ID;
    private string _CustomerGuid;
    //and so on

    public string setID(string Id){ _ID = Id;} 
    public string getID(){ return _ID;}

    public string setCustomerGuid(string customerGuid){ _CustomerGuid = customerGuid;} 
    public string getCustomerGuid(){ return _CustomerGuid;}
}
```

To get/parse the Json array, you could do something like this:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourApiReturnedJsonStringHere);
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    User user = new User();

    JSONObject jObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

    user.setID(jObj.getString("ID"));
    user.setCustomerGuid(jObj.getString("CustomerGuid"));
    //.....

    users.add(user);
}
```

Comment: yes thanks, i've now learnt that there are two options or getJsonObject and getJsonArray , still studying also,, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```c#
 var response = new ApiResponse<T>();
 response.Data = db.Users;
 return response;
```

This will encapsulate your list inside data name

If you are not using API controller then simply create Response  class and

```
public Response<T> : where T : class
{
  public T Data {get; set;}
}

return new Response<IList<Users>>() { Data = db.Users};
```

Answer (score 0):

hi all thankyou for your replies i've also found this post that fixed exactly my problem..

[MVC4: Include object name in Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043611/mvc4-include-object-name-in-json)